# Xubuntu 13.10 new app windows open with buttons at top of frame concealed

Tags: 13.10, xfce, window-manager, xfce-panel, xfwm4

In Xubuntu 13.10, many apps, such as Bluefish, Calibre and Firefox, when launched put their window off-kilter, high and to the right, so the top of the window's frame is concealed.  Pressing `{Alt-Enter} x` to revert to ordinary sizing is vexing. For programs which don't have size and position settings, how may I fix the location and size for opening windows, so the buttons at the top of the window are not hidden?

Tried using settings manager to click on `Window Manager Tweaks`, select the Placement tab, and slide the bar under "Minimum size of windows to trigger smart placement:" all the way to the right. This did not help.

It may be relevant that Panel 0 is at the top, and Panel 1 is at the left. Metacity is not in use. It happens whether or not `Display Compositing` is enabled in `Settings | Windows Manager Tweaks | Compositor`.

Comment: Had a similar problem and I slid the "Window tweaks" slider all the way to the left -- solved my problem! Now new windows open just where I closed them last time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem and I slid the "Window tweaks" slider all the way to the left -- solved my problem! Now new windows open just where I closed them last time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a ready solution for this. In my experience this happens, but somewhat rarely. When this happens I usually do `alt + mouse-click` to drag the window downwards until the WM buttons are visible.